# how to delete a post from database in React Native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, rest

i am trying to delete a post by its id from the database. I was able to implement the get and post methods in React Native but when i tried to delete it did not work.

here is my delete method in backend:-

```
 router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
 let { id } = req.params;
 Post.findByPk(id).then((post) => {
if (post) {
  return post.destroy().then(() => {
    res.status(204).send();
  });
} else {
  res.status(404).send();
}
  });
});
```

in React Native here is the code i am currently using:

```
 const deletePost = () => client.delete("/posts/:id");
```

here is my button, that when pressed calls the handleDelete function:

```
<Button title="Delete" onPress={handleDelete}/>
```

And here is my handle delete so far:

```
const handleDelete = () => {
  Alert.alert("Delete", "Are you sure you want to delete this post?", [
    { text: "Yes", onPress=},
    { text: "No" },
  ]);
 };
```

Can someone help me finish this? How do i call the deletePost method in my onPress?

Here is my Post Model in backend:

```
const Post = db.define(
 "Post",
 {
id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true,
},
title: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending id from client. You're passing a string ":id" in that route. Try below code.

```js
const deletePost = (id) => client.delete(`/posts/${id}`);

const handleDelete = (id) => {
  Alert.alert("Delete", "Are you sure you want to delete this post?", [
    { text: "Yes", onPress: () => deletePost(id) },
    { text: "No" },
  ]);
 };
```

Comment: hi nazeer, i tried something very similar and it worked. const deletePost = (PostId) => client.delete(`/posts/${PostId}`); 
const handleDelete = () => {
  Alert.alert("Delete", "Are you sure you want to delete this post?", [
    { text: "Yes", onPress: () => deletePost(post.id) },
    { text: "No" },
  ]);
 };

Comment: can you explain how my code worked? PostID is the column in the database

Comment: Glad to know that. Set this as answer, so others can know the correct way. Thank you

Comment: @kd12345 You're simply doing Post.findByPk(id) in your POST MODEL to find by id and then destroying it. It's nothing to do with your PostID column. By the way i'm frontend expert not backend but i can understand your api code.

Comment: so here const deletePost = (PostId) => client.delete(/posts/${PostId}) instead of PostId i call it anything?

Comment: Yes you can call it anything but on backend side you have to receive it like this req.params.id because of a "/:id". You forget to set this as answer.

Comment: will set it now, also why do i have to use `` instead of ""

Comment: hi @NazeerBinZafar , i was wondering can you help me out, i am trying to implement like and unlike button in react native

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const handleDelete = () => {
  Alert.alert("Delete", "Are you sure you want to delete this post?", [
    { text: "Yes", onPress: () => deletePost() },
    { text: "No" },
  ]);
 };
```

Comment: in frontend when i did that i got an unexpected token error because of the = after onPress, when i changed it to :, in my backend i got this error SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for type integer: ":id"

Comment: Try this way `onPress: () => {...}` as I have updated my answer too

Comment: so like this { text: "Yes", onPress: () => {deletePost()} } ?

Comment: in backend i am still getting this error SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for type integer: ":id"

Comment: I think type of `id` is not correct or invalid when coming on backend. You are expecting `integer` and it's not. Can you check the `id` of post? what's is exactly? or share some more info code

Comment: Hi Nooruddin, i have a very similar issue as this one again. here when i do console.log(posts) i get all my posts from backend. When i do console.log(posts.id) i get undefined but when i do console.log(posts[0].id) i get a value why does this happen?